# Adding another key to AOSP build

Tags: android, android-source

I have two different Android devices from two different vendors. Each has their own customized AOSP build (which I manage). I've one set of system-signed apps to install on both devices. I'd like to avoid having to sign each APK separately for each device.

I can do this by replacing the system certs in the AOSP builds (`target/product/security/platform.{pk8,x50.pem}`). But this would mean re-signing any vendor-supplied apps for each device. I'd like to avoid that.

How can I add a second system cert to each build? I'd sign my own apps with the matching key and have single APKs that would install on both devices. Vendor apps could retain their existing signature matching the original system key.

Answer (score 0):

You should your key files (pk8 and x509,pem) in the `target/product/security/your_new_key.{pk8,x50.pem}` directory and use this phrase in Android.mk files of your application:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := you_new_key
```

This app will then be signed using your new key.

For more info search about default keys present in AOSP (shared, media, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but all this does is (re-)sign apps during the build. If I want to rebuild and re-install just that app on both platforms after they are built this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Then you would have two ways: 1- Building a keystore with .pk8 and .x509.pem files and import that into Android studio and sign your apps. 2- use `build/tools/releasetools/sign_target_files_apk` See docstring of the related python script for more info @AllenLuce

Comment: I apologize if I didn't write the question well. What I want to do is have an Android build recognize more than one key as a system-signing key. Given what I've learned over the last few months, that doesn't seem possible without major changes to how AOSP handles signatures.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question at here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/57959598/5506167   thanks @AllenLuce